# x is divided by 3 and 4 implies its also divided by 6

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to show that if $[3$ divides $x$ and $4$ divides $x]$ then $[6$ divides $x]$.

I guess my starting point is something like
$x=3n$
$x=4m$

But how do i show that there is also a $c$ with
$x=6c$?

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Since twelve is divided by 3 and 4, as well as 2 and 6, it follows that anything divided by 3 and 4 (which implies 12), also divides by 6?

Comment: In fact, $x$ is divisible by $12$. Since $x = 3n = 4m$, it follows that $3|4$ or $3|m$ since $3$ is prime. But $3$ clearly does not divide $4$, so $3$ must divide $m$. The conclusion follows. In general, you can prove the stronger fact that if $\gcd(n,m) = 1$, then if $k$ is divisible by both $n$ and $m$, it is divisible by $nm$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this, which is generalisable:

$x=3n$ implies $4x=12n$

$x=4m$ implies $3x=12m$

Subtract to obtain $x=12(n-m)$

---

If $p$ and $q$ are both factors of $x$ we can write:

$x=pm=qn$

Now suppose that $p$ and $q$ are coprime. There is a theorem that we can find integers $a, b$ such that $ap+bq=1$.

We multiply this by $x$ to obtain $apx+bqx=x$ and we substitute carefully for $x$ on the left-hand side so that $$apqn+bpqm=pq(an+bm)=x$$And we see that $x$ is divisible by $pq$. You don't need to be able to prove the theorem to use it in a particular case - it tells you that if you look carefully to will find the $a$ and $b$ you need.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$x=3n=4m$$

This implies that $3$ divides $4m$. As $3$ is prime, it means it divides either $4$ or $m$. Can you take it from here?

P.S. It is not that important that $3$ is prime, the important part is that $3$ and $4$ are relatively prime.

Answer (score -2):

Since $3$ and $4$ divide $x$, $x$ must therefore equal $4 * 3 * n$ = $2*2*3*n$ for some $n$ (since 3 and 4 are relatively prime). Taking a new integer $m = 2n$, it is easy to see that $x = 2*3*m = 6*m$ for the integer $m$. Therefore, 6 divides $x$.

Comment: This answer is begging the question - in the first line, you assume what you are trying to prove. Furthermore, it's not true in general that if $m, n | k$ that $k$ is a multiple of $mn$. For example, both $2$ and $4$ divide $6$, but $6$ is not a multiple of $8$.

Comment: @AWertheim You mean 2 and 6 divide 6 but 12 doesn't divide 6... Note that 4 doesn't divide 6 ;)

Comment: Not so much begging the question as assuming facts about the prime factorisation of $x$. $x=4m$ and $3|x$ so $3|4$ or $3|m$ because $3$ is prime.

Comment: @N.S.: d'oh, thanks. Making errors all over the place today. :) Mark Bennet: sure, I guess I just meant the fact he is assuming amounts to assuming what he is trying to prove. You're right though.

Comment: @MarkBennet I've been mulling over this off and on for about a month now. How is my answer not correct? If x (not equal to zero) is both a multiple of 3 and 4, then x MUST be a multiple of 12, which shows that x is a multiple of 6.

Comment: I can't speak for others, but it seems to me that such a problem has two parts: the first a general(izable) verification that the thing you assume in the first line ($3\mid x, 4\mid x$ implies $12 \mid x$) is true, and the second the translation of that into the particular claim. The first part is almost certainly harder in my opinion, so to only give the second leaves the answer a bit wanting.